# Fetching values from database and storing in variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get database column values in some variable.
I dont want to use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
mysql_fetch_row
mysql_fetch_array
mysql_fetch_object
```

anyone of this.

My table is:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
| pcount   |       157 |
| ncount   |       210 |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to get 157, 210 in some variable `$x` and `$y`.
I am working in PHP.
**Can some one guide me.**?

One can do `$p= $mysqli->query('SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type=pcount');` and then iterate through all rows to fetch all values.

But I have only two rows and for my need I want to manually fetch the values of `Index_val`. IF someone can sort it out!

Comment: How about fetchColumn?

Comment: @Mihai: column could not be fetched. But elements could be with similar query I mentioned. But I dont know currect syntax.

Comment: @Mihai: In mysql `select * from view_name where ind_type='pcount';` gives me 157. Same thing I wanted in php and store in some variable. Your reputation does not owe this sort of description!

Comment: So what prevents you from using mysql assoc and do $variable=$row['pcount'] and in your query you use WHERE column='value' or LIMIT 1 or instead of while do if?

Comment: @Mihai: thanks but your explaination is bit confusing. I already tried a lot with no luck. Could you please write peace of line on your new answer and `echo` that variable?

Comment: Just a reminder, you should never use `mysqli_*` as it is outdated (and scheduled for removal in PHP6 I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this ?

```
if ($p = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT max(CASE when ind_type= 'pcount' then Index_val end) as x , 
                                  max(CASE when ind_type= 'ncount' then Index_val end) as y
   FROM view_name ")){

    $p->execute(); 
    $p->store_result();
    $p->bind_result($x , $y);
    $p->fetch() ;
     }
    echo $x ."<br />". $y ;
```

where ind_type=pcount then in your table will get only 157 is it only matched value.

EDIT:

for both values . either you dont need a condition , fetch all or make an OR condition.

```
if ($p = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type= ? OR ind_type= ? ")){
 $p->bind_param('ii', 'pcount' , 'ncount');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Anyways for both pcount and ncount in my table `$mysqli->prepare("SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type= ? ?")` or what?

Comment: And also you recommended not to use mysqli-> that what is it's alternative? even you also have used it. Just for my info

Comment: for both values . either you dont need a condition , fetch all or make an OR condition like that `where ind_type= ? OR where ind_type= ?`

Comment: thanks a lot. And binding should be done like this `$p->bind_result($Index_val1,$Index_val2);` for both values right?

Comment: with that variable you can do what you like with it. to filter which value u need.

Comment: variable means have many values inside it, but as you saying $x=157 its defined variable .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38353/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-echo-me)